# Identical query with same data which uses DATEDIFF fails in one and passes in one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two queries

```
use [DatabaseAA]
select *
,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,SomeDate,'3/28/2012 12:52:25  PM +00:00')
```

This passes, while the same query when executed against another database fails.

```
use [DatabaseBB]
select *
,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,SomeDate,'3/28/2012 12:52:25  PM +00:00')
```

fails in the DatabseBB

Both the sometime has same values. It is failing for the 3 parameter to the datediff. Any ideas why this is the case ?

The error message is

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: What is the `collation` of the databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will fail if the database's [compatibility level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933794.aspx) is 80 or 90 (SQL 2000/5) you need to set it to 100 for SQL 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Are both the SQL servers using the same date format?

You can see the current setting with `DBCC USEROPTIONS` and set it if necessary with `SET DATEFORMAT` (documentation for that is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)).